# Are there limits to how many div's a canvas element can be nested it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I have some webGL(threejs) rendering in canvas inside a div working exactly as I would think with the following structure...

```
<body>
   <div id='header'></div>
   <div id="webGLDiv">
      <script></script>
   </div>
   <div id='someInfo'></div>
</body>
```

However, when I nest webGLDiv into a parent div like this....

```
<body>
   <div id="websiteContents">
      <div id='header'></div>
      <div id="webGLDiv">
         <script></script>
      </div>
   <div id='someInfo'></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

In the browser the script information stays inside webGLDiv, but the canvas element gets pushed just above the closing body tag.

Does anyone no why this is happening? In my first example above, the canvas gets placed right after webGLDiv.

Comment: What canvas? I can see no canvas

Comment: That canvas element generates its at run time.  I'm self taught - this is the only way I've gotten it to work is in my first example.

Comment: The placement of the canvas [seems to](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene) depend on what you do with the renderer's `domElement` within the script. Can you also share that portion of your code?

Comment: Don't worry, most of us, if not all, are self taught :)

Comment: haha thanks for the encouragement!!  The link here is a link to the fiddle.  If I remove the "ab3d-website" div, it works just fine as described in the example above https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3zgJl4fEph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placement of the `<canvas>` is controlled by this line in the script:

```
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

The `renderer.domElement` is your `<canvas>` and the `document.body` is the parent element it's being placed within. (The position of the `<script>` element isn't used by Three.js for this.)

To change where it's placed, you'll want to specify a different parent element. To have that be the `<div id="webGLDiv">`, you could use:

```
document.getElementById('webGLDiv').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Lonowski, that did it!